# Roslyn project.Documents is empty when run on Build server

Tags: c#, mstest, roslyn, azure-pipelines

I have a unit Test that checks that all my service methods make a call to some authorization method.

I'm checking this in a unit Test using Roslyn.

The test runs fine on my local machine but fails on the build server, because project.Documents is empty.

I'm using VS 2017 and mstest V2.
The build server is a private on prem build agent in VSTS.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task All_public_Service_Methods_should_check_authorization()
{
    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
    var project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync(pathToCsprojFile).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine($"AssemblyName is {project.AssemblyName}"); // same output
    Console.WriteLine($"FilePath is {project.FilePath}"); // same output
    Console.WriteLine($"Documents are {string.Join(Environment.NewLine,project.Documents.Select(d => d.FilePath))}"); // empty on build server
    //...
}
```

This is the csproj, that I'm trying to load

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.5</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netstandard1.5\adremes.Exchange.Services.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netstandard1.5\adremes.Exchange.Services.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="adremes.Common" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Collection" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\adremes.Exchange.Common\adremes.Exchange.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\adremes.Exchange.Data\adremes.Exchange.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Not clear which build agent you used, Hosted VS2017, Hosted or on premise build agent (setup on your machine). I made the tests with Hosted VS2017 and on premise build agent, both of them works fine. This is my project (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AresBGZVYryjhSVqPERo60v8Ichb) What’re steps of your build definition? (I specified Visual Studio 2017 for Visual Studio Build and Latest version of VSTest for Visual Studio Test) Can you share detail build log here?

Comment: I experimented a bit more and found out that all my net core and netstandard projects seem to have no documents when this is run on the build server (on prem)

Comment: What's the result if you run the test on your build agent machine manually? What's the result of my project? Can you share a simple solution on the OneDrive?

Comment: What's the detailed result you get on your local machine?

Comment: I am running into a similar problem. I created very simple code based on example based on example: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Samples/CSharp/FormatSolution/Program.cs I suspect that this boils down to lack/wrong version of some packages which are referenced, such as Microsoft.Build, etc..

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this?

Comment: No, we had to disable this Test in our CI Builds